# Possible ways to get the group Last/Max record in a hierarchical query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion, hierarchical-data

Assuming I have a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE user_delegates (
    [id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_from] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [user_to] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_user_delegates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_user_delegates] UNIQUE ([user_from] ASC)
)
```

So an user A has to right to delegate her system access to another user B. When she does that, she won't be able to access the system anymore - user B will have to "break" that delegation before she is able to use the system again...

BUT also consider that, if user B delegates access to user C, user C *will also start impersonating user A*, and so on.

(I know this seems to be a security nightmare - please let's just forget about that, OK? :-))

Also consider those records:

```
INSERT INTO user_delegates([user_from], [user_to]) values ('ANTHONY', 'JOHN')
INSERT INTO user_delegates([user_from], [user_to]) values ('JOHN', 'JOHN')
INSERT INTO user_delegates([user_from], [user_to]) values ('KARL', 'JOSHUA')
INSERT INTO user_delegates([user_from], [user_to]) values ('JOSHUA', 'PIOTR')
INSERT INTO user_delegates([user_from], [user_to]) values ('PIOTR', 'HANS')
```

So what I need is finding the **last** (which means the active) delegation for each user.

I have come to a solution that I've decided to **not** show here (unless everybody ignores me, which is always a possibility). All I can say is that it is a somewhat long answer, and it surely seems like using a cannon to kill a flea...

But how would you do that? Consider any relevant SQL Server extension available, and notice we're looking for an answer that is both elegant and with a good performance...

BTW, this is the expected result set:

```
id          user_from  user_to   
----------- ---------- ----------
1           ANTHONY    JOHN      
2           JOHN       JOHN      
3           KARL       HANS      
4           JOSHUA     HANS      
5           PIOTR      HANS      

(5 row(s) affected)
```

And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH    q (user_initial, user_from, user_to, link) AS
        (
        SELECT  user_id, user_id, user_id, link
        FROM    users
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  user_initial, q.user_to, ud.user_to, link + 1
        FROM    q
        JOIN    user_delegates ud
        ON      ud.user_from = q.user_to
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_initial ORDER BY link DESC) rn
        FROM    q
        )
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Very good... But you missed something like a `WHERE ud.user_from != ud.user_to` on the query just after `UNION ALL` (without that the DB engine throws a "maximum recursion has been exhausted" error). But I guess it's just evil to have a rule like "JOHN delegates to JOHN"... Even if that's exactly what happens on the real application which this question was based upon. :P

Comment: @rsenna: if there is a loop, the query will naturally exceed the recursion limit and fail.

Comment: you mean to just ignore the error? OK, I'll consider that... Thanks!

Comment: @rsenna: not ignore, but take it as a sign of a loop (or delegation too deep).